# How to select the number of flop for clock cross domain for different register bus width?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

--Process 1 - register the single bit register coming asynchronously

```
process (clk,rst_n) begin -- 100 MHz clk
  if (rst_n='0') then
    reg_1bit_reg1_s <= '0';
    reg_1bit_reg2_s <= '0';
  elsif  rising_edge(clk) then
    reg_1bit_reg1_s <= tx_avl;--Coming at 50MHz
    reg_1bit_reg2_s <= reg_1bit_reg1_s;
  end if;
end process;
```

--Process 2 - register the 128bit register coming asynchronously

```
process (clk,rst_n) begin -- 100 MHz clk
  if (rst_n='0') then
    reg_128bit_reg1_s <= (others => '0');
    reg_128bit_reg2_s <= (others => '0');
  elsif  rising_edge(clk) then
    reg_128bit_reg1_s <= tx_avl_data;--Coming at 50MHz
    reg_128bit_reg2_s <= reg_128bit_reg1_s;
  end if;
end process;
```

The tx_avl and tx_avl_data asserts asynchronously at any time. Above registers are OK to handle the cross clock domain for 1-bit (tx_avl) and 128-bit(tx_avl_data) or I need to use more registers?

Comment: This site is about programming. Questions on HDLs are allowed, but your question is about electronics. There is a specific Stack Excahgne site for that [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: When you ask your question there, you might want to supply a bit more detail. The answer to your question re the one bit signal is almost certainly "2 flip-flops". However, in certain circumstances you might need more (but given your clock frequencies this is highly unlikely).

Comment: but the answer to your question re the 128-bit signal is not straight forward. It almost certainly isn't "256 flip-flops", but depends on the protocol of this signal (ie how it relates to the single bit signal). So, you would want to add that information to your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the electronics Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Thanks Taylor. I will the code for better understanding,

Comment: process (clk,rst_n) begin -- 100 MHz clk
  if (rst_n) then
    reg_128bit_reg1_s <= '0';
    reg_128bit_reg2_s <= '0';
  elsif  rising_edge(clk) then
    reg_128bit_reg1_s <= tx_avl_data;--Coming at 50MHz
    reg_128bit_reg2_s <= reg_128bit_reg1_s;
  end if;
end process;

The tx_avl and tx_avl_data asserts asynchronously at any time.

Comment: As I said, you're better off asking this on the Electronics Stack Exchange site - [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the bits independently, your code is fine, assuming your tx_ signals come from registers in their 50 MHz domain. Each bit line gets 2 flip-flops in the 100MHz, and will be fine, without metastability problems (for most current technologies).
Now, if you want to use the data as a bus, you will have lots of problems, as it shouldn't be done like that at all. Currently, for a transition from 000 to 111 you will sometimes go through all possible bus values, like 000->101->111, or 000->110->111 !
The bus is supposed to be strobed at once when not changing value (and frozen while changing values), which is likely indicated by your tx_avl, but completely depends on the kind of bus you're using.
In some cases you may be better off using a dual port/dual clock memory block...
Also note that each one clock pulse in the 50 MHz domain will become a 1 OR 2 clock pulse in the 100 MHz domain, which may not be what you expect!